# PHP Time if extends

Tags: php, datetime

for now this is what my code contains

index.html

```
<form action="timeout.php" method="POST">
<input type="time" name="txt_time" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

timeout.php

```
<?php
$formattedTime = date("h:i A", strtotime($_POST['txt_time']));
$curfew = date("h:i A", strtotime('20:00'));
if($formattedTime > $curfew) {
 echo "You are past the curfew time";
} else {
 echo "Success";
}
?>
```

My problem is, even if I put for exampole 08:00 AM on that day, it still says You are past the curfew time. Any thoughts?

Comment: So if the input is "3:00 PM" or "14:00" you want to evaluate if that time is before a set curfew? Don't use `str2time()` for that.

Comment: `<input type="time" />`? that ain't supported on all browsers

Comment: @Twisty the input type is time, what should I use then?

Comment: @Ghost I am using polyfiller.js so it would work on other browsers

Comment: @FewFlyBy what? no you don't understand, its not supported by other browsers, it'll be just a normal text input on others. try it on firefox or ie to find out

Comment: @AlphaDelta got it. I was not thinking about Time formats that were lacking the Date. And my thinking was wrong.

Comment: @Ghost It is working because I am using polyfiller.js. You can check my screenshots. First image is on firefox, second on IE and third on chrome. http://imgur.com/a/mx1NJ

Comment: @Ghost This one http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/

Comment: @FewFlyBy oh okay, you're using a plugin, i thought you were using the plan input time

Comment: @Ghost Yes I am using a plugin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `date()` function formats a timestamp to a string, when you compare the two strings using `$formattedTime > $curfew` PHP converts the two strings to integers, which would make something like `8:41 AM` simply `8`.

Here's a quick sloppy hack that should work correctly

```
<?php
$formattedTime = intval(date("Hi", strtotime($_POST['txt_time'])));
$curfew = intval(date("Hi", strtotime('20:00')));
//'H' will get the hour of the time from 0-23, intval will convert that to an integer

if($formattedTime > $curfew) {
    echo "You are past the curfew time";
} else {
    echo "Success";
}
?>
```

[Example](http://3v4l.org/bDmC7)

Comment: Hello this works. Now my problem is whenever I select a time between 8-9PM like 8:01-8:59 it still echo's success, I wanted it to echo "You are past the curfew time";

Comment: You probably used the old code with just `H` in the `date()`, try with `Hi` instead which accounts for minutes. If you want to go as far as to check the exact second as well use `His`.

Comment: Oh yes I used the old code. Now it works, will mark your answer as best after few minutes. Thank you

Comment: If I want to make the curfew 6:00 PM I will just change 20:00 to 18:00 right?

Comment: IIRC you could just make it `6:00 PM` and `strtotime()` will work its magic on it, but yes `18:00` is equally as valid.